# CollapsingToolbarLayout not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I've looked through similar questions on SO and also the docs.  I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.  The CollapsingToolbar doesn't collapse.  The recyclerview slides underneath it when scrolling it up the screen.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note:  I've tried adding the

```
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to the recyclerview instead of the SwipeRefreshLayout and also have tried removing the SwipeRefreshLayout altogether.

Below is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/logo"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not set the recycler.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed
```

to the Toolbar.  Having it in the CollapsingToolbarLayout isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" to your recyclerview